# MSSQL2000: get list of role members

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

I know a role name and want to find all users in this role. 
How do I acheive this in SQL Server 2000 (in the SQL script, not in Management Studio or other tool)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following stored procedures:

For fixed server roles, the stored procedure is [sp_helpsrvrolemember](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188772.aspx):

```
exec sp_helpsrvrolemember 'role'
```

For general roles, the stored procedure is [sp_helprolemember](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178021.aspx):

```
exec sp_helprolemember 'role'
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use SQL-DMO:
Replace *rolename* with your role

```
exec sp_helprolemember rolename
```